# Mood's median test - an apparent paradox

Tags: hypothesis-testing, median

I have collected some data about systolic blood pressure in kids. Altogether, I have collected 500 measurements of blood pressure - 300 measurements for girls and 200 measurements for boys. The pressure measurements in the subsamples (subsamplea=boys, subsampleb=girls) are not normally distributed. This is also true for the collection of all 500 measurements (i.e. the whole sample data are not normally distributed, too).
The blood pressure medians for the subsamples (and the sample as a whole) **are the same** and amount to 105 mmHg.
How is it possible that the results of the Mood's test indicate that there is a statistically significant difference between the medians of girls' and boys' systolic blood pressure???
The Median test (as implemented in SPSS) output shows that in 30% percent of the boys and in 40% of the girls the blood pressure was higher than the (combined) median, which is 105 mmHg. Taking into account that the Mood's test breaks down to a chi-square test, the quoted difference in the percentages could explain the statistical significance of the test.
**However, don't these percentages contradict the definition of the median??? Shouldn't there be 50% measurements above the median in each of the groups???**
Remember: the subsample medians are in this example equal to the whole sample median.

Could this result be related to the fact that the proportion of kids with exactly 105mmHg (the median value)is much higher in the girls sub-sample than in the boy sub-sample.

Comment: What you are saying sounds strange. If the two medians are equal the test cannot be signifiant. Might there be some technical nuances, such as weighting or missing data, that you pass over silently? Can you give the data, for somebody here to check?

Comment: Also, saying of the combined median, do you mean the median of the 200+300 total sample?

Comment: Many statisticians consider this test to be obsolete.  That was the subject of an article in _The American Statistician_ some years ago.  It is too inefficient, and it is easy to see why because of the information it discards.

Comment: @ ttnphns When I say combined median, yes I think of the "total sample" median (median based on all 500 observations). However, I will probably follow Harrell's suggestion and avoid using the Mood's test - I will go on with the Mann-Whitney test. Thank you for your comments.

Comment: Sure, the test is blunt. @Frank, can you share the paper or a link? statquest: you may use M-W, of course; but be aware that this test is, generally, not a test of specifically _medians_.

Comment: http://www.citeulike.org/user/harrelfe/article/13265551